# How to can i set handlers to all links with real href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors, handler

I use jQuery 2.1.1 and i have this code:

```
//Load and execute script via AJAX
function loadScript(e) {
        $.getScript($(e.target).attr("href")).error(function (error) {
            $.notify("Request error"); 
        });
    return false; //Cancel opening link in the browser
}

//Set handlers to all <a> elements with href attribute and href!='#'
Desktop.prototype.init = function () {
    $("body").on("click", $("a[href][href!='#']"), {}, loadScript);
};
```

When I make click in one place of the document, I see error message (404). Why? What should I write in this situation? I will load and execute scripts dynamically by click on the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following syntax for event delegation on anchor elements that do not have an href value of `#`.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a:not([href="#"])', loadScript);
```

[Here's a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaj82kwg/)